# Do no-index no-follow on certain links

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have random text:

Using JavaScript I need to replace links no-follow and no-index. How I can do this?

I tried:

```js
$('.content').html().replace('example.com', '<a href="example.com" rel="nofollow">Example</a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae blanditiis cum numquam qui iure odit. Ipsum beatae magni dicta quibusdam natus. Necessitatibus voluptas nobis <a href="http://example.com">example</a>, esse culpa? Suscipit, consequatur,
    debitis.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. <a href="http://example.com">Example 1</a> ullam, vitae laborum aliquam officiis similique, magnam fugiat, <a href="http://example2.com">maxime</a> itaque repellendus iure. Et voluptatem quae
    tenetur neque accusamus atque consectetur totam.
  </p>
</div>
```

But I get always original text. Why?

Comment: But your html hasn't raw URL and both URL is link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to replace the html....just target those links using an [attributeContains selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$('.content a[href *="example.com"]').attr('rel','nofollow')
```

For a more generic approach for all external links use `filter()` and check host of link against host of your page

```
$('.content a').filter(function(){
    return this.host !== location.host
}).attr('rel','nofollow')
```

Comment: What I was going to do also reference https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/links.html#link-type-nofollow and http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: You could also add an example for the `filter` with the `example.com` where `href equals (vs `example2.com`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss sure...could come up with all sorts of scenarios....but question is not very specific regarding full intent

Answer (score 0):

### Adding rel nofollow and noindex to links in your document with vanilla JavaScript

If you want to add the `rel` attribute to all links in document using plain JavaScript you can use the following snippet:

```js
// Get all anchor tags in document
const selector = 'a';
const links = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

// Add rel='nofollow noindex' attribute to each
[].forEach.call(links, link => {
  link.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow noindex')
});
```

### Adding rel nofollow noindex to specific links only

If you want to be more specific you can tweak the `selector` to only match the links you want to transform.

As an example you could add a specific class to the links you want to transform and target them with the selector value `a.your-class-name`.

### Using attribute selectors

Or you could match [based on the href attribute value with an attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#Syntax)

You can use this to only target the links to https://example.com but not the links targeting another domain by using the following selector: `a[href^=https://example.com]` (the `^=` means beginning with).

If you want to do it only on links with a `target="_blank"` you can use the `a[target=_blank]` selector.

If you want to do it on links having a `target` attribute, no matter the value you can use `a[target]` as a selector.

### Example targeting only links to example.com:

```js
// Get all anchor tags matching `selector` in document
const selector = 'a[href^=https://example.com]';
const links = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

// Add rel='nofollow noindex' attribute to each
[].forEach.call(links, link => {
  link.setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow noindex')
});
```

Comment: Given the question, this might perhaps filter on the `example.com` value also

Comment: Unsure I understand your comment, but just added an example with an attribute selector to only match links to http://example.com and not http://example2.com